# Apply Discount over shipping cost only - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce I'want to apply discount coupon on shipping cost only. I'm providing only shipping service to my customer and offering some discount via coupon, So, I just want to apply that discount amount on Shipping Cost only?

Comment: Tell us what you have done so far?

Comment: I've implemented default option for coupon discount available with woocommerce. But It applies only on cart total, in my case cart total would be $0 always. So, I want it to apply on shipping cost only.

Comment: I would suggest adding more content to this question, to help us get to the answer that you need to resolve this problem. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and review your question. In addition, StackOverflow is not a code writing service. StackOverflow will help to identify bugs, or faults in code, but will not come up with code for you. If you have attempted this yourself, please show us so that we can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide coupons on the basis of shipping method. In this case, the coupon will be applied only to those customers who use the linked shipping method. The coupon can also be made to apply for certain customers based on location. The free coupon extension plugin [Smart coupon for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wt-smart-coupons-for-woocommerce/) lets you do this.

Answer (score 0):

**WooCommerce developers** do not support this kind of **discount**. see the attached image below:

[image]

> however, maybe following hack could work:

you need to edit `wc-admin-functions.php` file, you can find it inside `woocommerce=>includes=>admin` directory.

Search and find this:

`update_post_meta( $order_id, '_cart_discount', $subtotal - $total );`

and replace it with the following one:

```
update_post_meta( $order_id, '_cart_discount', $total_shipping_tax );
```

I personally, do not like this way, the better way could be override this statement from `functions.php` file of your active theme, or you should hook this code into a suitable `WooCommerce Action`.

so whenever you or your client update the plugin your change remain unaffected. let me know if you find any other solutions that work.

Comment: Thanks Tarun for you response, But It doesn't work for me. Still it is calculating discount on cart total Only

Comment: when you created the coupon, what type of discount you choose, from dropdown list

Comment: It was Cart % Discount

Comment: ok, please use the first option **Cart Discount** for the coupon

Comment: It is a kind of flat discount, what about Percentage discount?